# Cannot use filter inside ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to apply filter to values inside ng-repeat? I'm trying to cut long strings inside a loop but Angular ignores my filter. No result. No errors. Nothing. Why?

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in event.log track by $index">
    <td>{{entry.raiseDate}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.text | cut}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.sign}}</td>
</tr>

angular.module('app.event')

.filter('cut', [function cut() {
    console.debug('im here');  // never called
    return function(input) {
        console.debug(input);
        var result;
        if ( input.length > 100 ) {
            result = input.substring(0, 100) + '...';
        } else {
            result = input;
        }
        return input;
    };
}]);
```

I also tried the predefined "lowercase" filter and it's not working too

Comment: Yes  it is possible, you can try with currency filter, you'll see it works. (Answer the question but doesn't solve your problem)

Comment: I tried the predefined "lowercase" filter and it's not working too.

Comment: Predefined filters needs "ng-filter" dependency to be added. Is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error with `.filter('cut', [function cut() {`, it should be `.filter('cut', ['cut', function(cut) {` or `.filter('cut', function() {`

Check the [filter doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Try the below code:

```
.filter('cut', ['cut', function(cut) {
    console.debug('im here');  // never called
    return function(input) {
        console.debug(input);
        var result;
        if ( input.length > 100 ) {
            result = input.substring(0, 100) + '...';
        } else {
            result = input;
        }
        return input;
    };
}]);
```

or

```
.filter('cut', function () {
    console.debug('im here');  // never called
    return function(input) {
        console.debug(input);
        var result;
        if ( input.length > 100 ) {
            result = input.substring(0, 100) + '...';
        } else {
            result = input;
        }
        return input;
    };
});
```

Comment: The problem is not in syntax. Predefined Angular filters are also not working.

Comment: Can you create a `plunkr/jsfiddle`, it will give you more response.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply filter to values inside ng-repeat

Try below code in your

```
 <td>{{entry.text | limitTo: 100 }} {{entry.text > 100 ? '...' : ''}}</td>
```